# Magento 2 - Stuck Checkout loader

Tags: error, composer, magento-2.1.2

Checkout loader gets stuck while processing an order, but the order is proceeding.

I found an error in console.

I have attached an image of what is happening, and a screen grab of the javascript error presented by the console on the browser.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Seems like there is a error with the Alotheme magiccart scripts.
please Run below commands via ssh.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```